# Unique key prop in react giving a warning even after I set a key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below code I am making a note card element with a unique key. The problem is whenever I try to edit my note element it gives me a warning as -
**Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**

Here is a part of my Notes component:-

```
       <ul className="d-flex flex-wrap col-md-12 justify-content-evenly m-2 list-unstyled"> 
        {notes.length > 0
          ? notes
              .toReversed()
              .map((note) => <NoteCard key={note._id} note={note}></NoteCard>)
          : "No notes found"}
         
      </ul>
```

And here is my Notecard component:-

```
return (
    <>
      
        <div className="card m-2" key={_id}>
          <div className="card-body position-relative overflow-auto">
            <h5 className="card-title">{title}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">
              {description.length < 47
                ? description
                : description.slice(0, 50) + "..."}
            </p>
            <span
              type="button"
              className="stretched-link"
              data-bs-toggle="modal"
              data-bs-target={`#cardModal-${_id}`}
              onClick={() => handleNoteEdit(_id)}
            ></span>
            <div
              className="modal fade"
              id={`cardModal-${_id}`}
              tabIndex="-1"
              aria-labelledby={`cardModalLabel-${_id}`}
              aria-hidden="true"
              data-bs-backdrop="static"
              data-bs-keyboard="false"
              data-bs-animation="flip-up"
            >
              <div className="modal-dialog">
                <div className="modal-content">
                  <div className="modal-header">
                    <h1
                      className="modal-title fs-5"
                      id={`cardModalLabel-${_id}`}
                    >
                      Edit Note
                    </h1>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn-close"
                      data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                      aria-label="Close"
                      onClick={clearNoteForm}
                    ></button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="modal-body">
                    <>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        value={inputTitle}
                        onChange={handleFormTitleChange}
                        className="form-control mb-2"
                      />
                      <textarea
                        value={inputDescription}
                        onChange={handleFormDescriptionChange}
                        className="form-control"
                        rows="3"
                      ></textarea>
                    </>
                  </div>
                  <div className="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={handleEditSubmit}>
                      Save changes
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-secondary"
                      data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                      onClick={clearNoteForm}
                    >
                      Close
                    </button>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="card-footer">
            <button
              href="#"
              className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
              style={{ width: "-webkit-fill-available" }}
              onClick={()=>handleNoteDelete(_id)}
            >
              Delete Note
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </>
```

This is the updateNote function:-

```
const handleEditSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const updatedNote = {
      title: inputTitle,
      description: inputDescription,
    };
  
    updateNote(_id, updatedNote);
  };
```

I tried setting the key to the jsx fragment of the notecard element, also on indivdual card element as well as set a useEffect to set the _id on the card element but none removed the warning.
I would be really helpful if someone helps me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `updateNote(_id, updatedNote);`: it's not clear where `_id` is coming from. I suspect during the update process you're not using the same id for the updated object which is why React is complaining. Difficult to tell without seeing the rest of the code (state update, how the function is being called.) [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: You are right the real problem is on another file. The _id is not the problem here I messed it up when setting the notes again after every update of notes in NoteContext.

Answer (score 1):

in your case, you have wrapped your component in <> </> and after that tag you have added a key in  tag so you have to add key in main warpper,

you can remove <> </> tag and directly wrap your code like,

```
return (
  <div className="card m-2" key={_id}>
   //your code
  </div>
 )
```

or

if <></> is necessary then use use React.Fragment to wrap your component

```
 return (
       <React.Fragment key={_id}>
         <div className="card m-2">
           //your code
         </div>
       </React.Fragment>
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried this before but none worked. Then I realized that the error was coming from the NoteContext. I had messed it up by setting the notes again with resolved data from the database.